# Pine script trade, can't get If else statement working

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I have a drop-down choice that works ok, and can't figure out how to get If else 
statement to work. Did try If for all of them, then if else and nothing is working. else (typ4 == rma) << is not working

Pine gives the following error, any help be really appreaciated
Mismatched input 'wma' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Testing", overlay=true)
showSMA2 = input(title="Toggle WMA/RMA/VWMA/VWAP/HullMA", type=input.bool, defval=true)
typ4 = input(title="Choice", defval="WMA", options=["WMA", "RMA", "VWMA", "VWAP", "HullMA"])
len4 = input(9, minval=1, maxval=8, title="Length")
src4 = input(title="Source OHLC", type=input.source, defval=close)

out =   if (typ4 == wma)
            wma(src4, len4)
        if typ4 == rma
            rma(src4, len4)

        if (typ4 == vwma)
            vwma(src4, len4)
        if (typ4 == vwap)
            vwap(src4, len4)

        if (typ4 == hullma)
            hullma(src4, len4)

plot(out, title="Custom", color=iff(showSMA2, color.green, na))
```

Also tried below, error at end of line out4
Mismatched input 'WMA1' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

```
WMA1 = wma(src4, len4)
RMA1 = rma(src4, len4)
VWMA1 = vwma(src4, len4)
VWAP1 = vwap(src4, len4)
HullMA = wma(src4, len4)

out4 = if (typ4 == WMA) WMA1
     if (typ4 == RMA) RMA1
     if (typ4 == VWMA) VWMA1
     if (typ4 == VWAP) VWAP1
     if (typ4 == HullMA) HullMA1
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I should have had read the documentation better for the drop-down input requirements instead of presuming how it will be, bad habit of thinking

```
//@version=4
strategy("Testing", overlay=true)
type1 = input(title="Choice", defval="WMA", options=["WMA", "RMA", "VWMA"])
len4 = input(9, minval=1, maxval=50, title="Length")
src4 = input(title="Source OHLC", type=input.source, defval=close)
plot(type1 == "WMA" ? wma(src4,len4) : type1 == "RMA" ? rma(src4,len4) : na)
```